# How to arrange the data in a particular manner

Tags: sap-ase

I tried making query but not getting how and where to start.
I have below data:

```
cob_date            load_date           batch
03/07/2017 00:00    04/07/2017 11:42    abc
03/07/2017 00:00    04/07/2017 16:12    def
03/07/2017 00:00    05/07/2017 05:11    ghi
```

and I need the output in below format (`Load_date` is `run_date` in output)

```
cob_date    RunDate(abc and def)    RunDate(ghi)    Time Produced (abc) Time Produced (def) Time Produced (ghi)
```

Need these columns ...  I need to seperate date and time from `load_date` column according to batch and need the output in above format as per `batch(abc,def,ghi)`.

Could someone please help me in making this query.

Comment: Can someone please help

Comment: What is `time produced` ? how do you calculate `rundate (abc and def)` ?